# SQLAlchemy Polymorphism: Parent table does not exist when creating a child record

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When trying to commit a record the following exception arises:

```
OperationalError (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
table: basedocument [SQL: INSERT INTO basedocument (common_field,
doc_type) VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: ('humanidade', 'user')]
```

**basedocument** is the parent table in a polimorphic association, and **user** is the child table.

Shouldn't the parent table be created when I create a record on a child table?

Here's the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp.db")
sessao = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class BaseDocument(Base):
    __tablename__ = "basedocument"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_field = Column(String)
    doc_type = Column(String(20))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "basedocument",
        "polymorphic_on": doc_type,
    }


class User(BaseDocument):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("basedocument.id"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "user",
    }


u1 = User(
    name="Dumont",
    fullname="Santos Dumont",
    nickname="voador",
    common_field="humanidade",
)
sessao.add(u1)
sessao.commit()
print("\nObject:  ", u1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just noticed that I forgot to use

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

after the classes definitions. This is what really creates the tables.

This answer is valid for many questions around the "No such table" error.

The right code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp.db")
sessao = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class BaseDocument(Base):
    __tablename__ = "basedocument"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_field = Column(String)
    doc_type = Column(String(20))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "basedocument",
        "polymorphic_on": doc_type,
    }


class User(BaseDocument):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("basedocument.id"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "user",
    }


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

u1 = User(
    name="Dumont",
    fullname="Santos Dumont",
    nickname="voador",
    common_field="humanidade",
)
sessao.add(u1)
sessao.commit()
print("\nObject:  ", u1)
```